# Trying to remove HTML-element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

If width of the device visiting my site is <320 I want a `<h3>` to be removed. This is what I've tried with:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="title">Title</h3>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 320) {

    document.write("Testing");

    var h3 = document.getElementById("title");

    h3.parentNode.removeChild(h3);
}
```

The "testing" label is printed on the screen but the `<h3>`is still there. What's wrong?

Comment: @Farrokh That's jQuery, which the OP didn't specify he uses.

Answer (score 3):

At the time the script is executed, the `h3` element has not been parsed, so it doesn't exist in the DOM.

Move the part of the script that removes it to after the `h3` in the HTML.

Better yet, forget about using JavaScript and use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) with `h3 { display: none; }` instead.

Comment: Yes I know I can use that but in my case I want to remove the `h3` to add it again inside a new `<a>` created with JavaScript as well. Thanks for the answer